# Identify if list contains not unique values without countif in a helper column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
      A           B        C     
1   Product A     1      Error
2   Product B     1
3   Product C     2
4   Product C     2
5   Product D     1
6   Product E     1
7
8
```

In the table above I want to identify if the values in `Column A` are unique. 
If there is at least one value which is not unique `Error` should be displayed in `Cell C1`. 
In order to achieve this I went with helper `Column B` and with the following formulas:

```
Column B `=COUNTIF($A$1:$A$6,A2)`
Cell C1 =`IF(COUNTA($A$1:$A$6)<SUM($B$1:$B$6),"Error","OK")`
```

All this works fine.

---

Now, I am wondering if there is also way to avoid the helper column. 
Basically, a formula that goes through `Column A` and if it identfies **at least one not-unique** value it should display `Error` in `Cell C1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=IF(MAX(COUNTIF($A$1:$A$6,$A$1:$A$6))>1,"Error","OK")
```

This is an array formula and depending on one's version will require the confirmation of Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

If one has the dynamic formula `UNIQUE()` then:

```
=IF(COUNTA(UNIQUE($A$1:$A$6))<>COUNTA($A$1:$A$6),"Error","OK")
```

As a normal formula.

Another formula, that will work in Conditional formatting:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MATCH($A$1:$A$6,A:A,0)<>ROW($A$1:$A$6)))>0
```